# See elements of $H^1(\mathcal{O}_X)$ as repartitions

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve of genus $g$ over an algebraically closed field $k$.

Define the ring of repartitions of $X$ (or adeles) as the set whose elements are collections $\{ r_P \}_{P\in X}$ with $r_P \in \mathcal{O}_{X,P}$ for all but finitely many $P\in X$. Notice that $R$ is a ring with the usual sum and multiplication of germs, but it can also be seen as a vector space over $k$.

Further, for any effective divisor $D$ on $X$, let $R(D)$ be the sub-vector space of $R$ consisting of those collections $\{ r_P \}_{P\in X} \in R$ such that $ v_P(r_P) + v_P(D) \geq 0. $

The interesting fact is that there is a canonical isomorphism
$$ \frac{R}{R(D) + k(X)} \cong H^1(\mathcal{O}_X(D)), $$

where $k(X)$ is the function field of $X$.

The proof can (for example) be found in seciton 4 of [these notes from Ravi Vakil](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/725/bagsrr.pdf), but it doesn't give an explicit map that realizes the isomorphism. So the question is:

**Could you help me understanding how to describe the explicit map realizing the above canonical isomorphism?**